# How to compare the changes between local changes and remote repository

Tags: git, github, egit, github-api, jgit

I want to synchronize changes with a remote Git repository (at GitHub) using the Git Api in Java (Egit and JGit). How can I do this? Is this possible by knowing the HEAD ID between two revisions, or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just knowing the `HEAD` of each of the two repositories is enough to tell you if they're out of sync but it is not enough to tell you which one is ahead of the other. In the general case, more than one person can push to a repository so assuming your local repository is always ahead of your remote would not be wise. You would have to use the API to find the first common SHA and using that determine how to handle synchronizing your repositories. You'll have to handle three (really more) cases:

1. Your local branch is ahead of your remote
2. Your remote is ahead of your local
3. Your local and remote both have sets of commits not on the other, e.g., you pushed from one computer but didn't pull here or someone else pushed commits recently and you didn't notice, etc.

The first two cases are trivial, the third is far more complex. You will always have to pull before you can synchronize your local changes with the remote and pulling could result in merge conflicts. If you are not careful you could break some code by trying to force a commit when a conflict has arisen.

Comment: Thanks for describing all the three scenarios.I can take care of it while working.But in my application there is a "Schedule Refresh" feature which works assuming that remote is always ahead of local(as you stated in second case) and refreshes itself with the remote one(i.e. replaces itself with the latest state of the remote repository).This is what I want to achieve using Git Api in Java.Pls suggest how can this be done.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Java APIs frankly but I would advise against implementing this. I can only guess that this is going to cause far more headaches than it will help you. If you simply start using better git practices, you will find that you never needed this. That is tangential to this question though so feel free to email me for more details.

Comment: ok but can u suggest command in git bash which could do this by just knowing the HEAD ID.I will find Java code equivalent to that command.